# An alternative to CodeTabs B+

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tabs, navigation, jquery-ui-tabs

Im looking for an alternative to the jquery library [CodeTabs B+](http://codecanyon.net/item/codetabs-b-premium-tabs-slider-for-bootstrap/full_screen_preview/8278901).
It should be possible to drag-and-drop the tab-navigation (important for mobile users). Do you know any?

Answer (score 0):

I found [http://owlgraphic.com/](http://owlgraphic.com). It fits some of the features CodeTabs B+ has.